# Why there are link errors when linking from win32 project to x64 library?

Tags: c++, 64-bit

I am using a library which has x86 and x64 versions. My project is win32, and when I linked to x64 library, I got a bunch of link errors.

I am wondering why I get those link errors. X64 versions use efferent symbol names?

Comment: You got link errors because 32-bit and 64-bit executables cannot be linked to each other. It can't possibly work.

Comment: It's no fun trying to guess the error messages. You can see them. We can't. Don't be shy.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mismatch in the size of pointers etc. You need to either compile for 32 bit or 64 bit using the appropriate libraries.

Comment: @David Heffenam - That is why I put etc.

Comment: I'd have thought the different instruction set, ABI, exception model etc. would all be rather bigger issues.